userAgentData within https iframe
I had a question about html pages. I have an html page that I navigate to via http, and in this page, I have an iframe that loads in an https page from a different domain that supports https. I am in control of both the http and https server, and I would like to access the navigator.userAgentData property from the https iframe - how would I be able to do this?
Just to give the html landing page code, this is what I have:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Welcome to ABCXYZ</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome to abcxyz.local!</h1>
    <p>This is the homepage served by the Flask server.</p>

    <iframe src="https://server.local:443" width="1" height="1" style="border:none;"></iframe>
</body>
</html>

I have a function from this landing page that is deployed from server.local which calls the navigator.userAgentData

You can't access variables in a different domain directly. You'll need to use postMessage() to send messages between the two frames.

so I need the userAgentData to be sent to server.local, not the abcxyz.local - why would I need to send messages between the two frames @Barmar

I thought you wanted to get it in JavaScript, not on the server.

Why would userAgentData be different in the two iframes? It identifies the browser, which is the same for all iframes.

@Barmar the userAgentData cannot be accessed in the HTTP page, but I can access that property from an HTTPs page, I was wondering if an HTTPs page that I inject into an iframe can allow me to access the navigator property or not

If you need userAgentData to be sent to server.local, why do you need to access it in the HTTP page? server.local is the HTTPS page. Add JavaScript to the HTTPS page that sends it using AJAX.

Please clarify your question because by design https pages can already access userAgentData in javascript, so it's unclear what the problem is and why a server is involved or why it's important that there's also an http page.

@woxxom @Barmar I need to be abel to access the https attribute of userAgentData from the HTTP page for a test, I know it would be easier to access it from the HTTPs page itself on server.local, but ideally if there is a way to pass this value to abcxyz.local then that would be appreciated to know.
